# Testcontainers Selenium how to update browser?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, testcontainers

I use Testcontainers (1.14.1) with Selenium (4.0.0-alpha-5) and Chrome to run my Java Integration Tests.

But when I run my tests my Angular Frontend aren't rendered. As I found out it's because the Chrome Version inside the container is to old. The Chrome has Version 43.
So to fix my tests I have to update Chrome.

But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution:** Use latest stable Selenium Version! In my case `3.141.59`

How I found the Solution:

As I found out, Selenium has current Chrome Versions as [Docker Tags](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome-debug/tags).

So the Problem had to be on Testcontainers side. I searched for how they know which container tag to use and found this:

```java
    /**
     * Based on the JARs detected on the classpath, determine which version of selenium-api is available.
     * @return the detected version of Selenium API, or DEFAULT_SELENIUM_VERSION if it could not be determined
     */
    public static String determineClasspathSeleniumVersion() {
```

[Whole source at GitHub](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/672cbeebcac6310caab90383bce11a0b753b1106/modules/selenium/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/SeleniumUtils.java#L29)

I looked into my Selenium API jar and there was the problem no `Selenium-Version` inside the manifest. And no container tag for the 4.0.0-alpha-5 of Selenium. So I just downgraded to the last stable version of Selenium.